# Does spring answer requests after service is stopped

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am just debugging some endpoints in Spring Boot and found out that after stopping the application while still pausing at some breakpoint in the endpoint function I still get a HTTP Response from it. Checked it with an Android client and with Postman and got the same result.

Is this behavior normal (some default graceful shutdown or so)? How to deactivate it?
Btw my IDE is IntelliJ.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint, you effectively stop the shutdown (or at least pause it) and as the server is still up it will handle requests.

Comment: But is there no way of shutting down immediately while debugging?

Comment: If the process would be shutdown, there would be nothing left to debug.

Comment: What I wanted so say is: While pausing at a breakpoint, I want to shutdown the app without the endpoint I am currently stopping at completing its request and send a response.

Comment: As stated that cannot be done. You cannot shutdown and debug as debugging will stop the shutdown. Or if the shutdown would continue it would stop debugging (because the process you are debugging would be gone).